# Можно ли добавить множество классов к тегу в HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Мне нужно добавить к множеству элементов один и тот же box-shadow который мне нужно будет менять через js и для удобства я создал class с этим box-shadow,, но подключив он не работает, т.к я понимаю он конфличит с классами самого тега

```css
.shadow-all {
    box-shadow: 2px 4px 6px rgb(255, 255, 255, .8);
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar" id="main-teme-chang" class="shadow-all">
```

Comment: Добавьте код, как именно вы пытаетесь это сделать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: для того чтобы Вам ответили, пожалуйста разместите код, не понятно что значит фраза "конфличит с классами самого тега". Можно ли добавить множество классов к тегу - да, но последний в стилях css  будет перебивать схожие свойства, не зависимо от того каким он будет в списке классов элемента

Comment: class = "navbar shadow-all" or class = "shadow-all navbar"

Comment: Классы нужно указывать через пробел, а не отдельными атрибутами.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Задает стилевой класс, который позволяет связать определенный тег со стилевым оформлением. **В значении допускается указывать сразу несколько классов, разделяя их между собой пробелом**.

Если бы вы хотя бы мельком прочитали о атрибуте [class](http://htmlbook.ru/html/attr/class)

Comment: Я помню что можно было подключать множество классов, но забыл что пробелами. Спасибо большое!